# Padding force a block element to line wrap

Tags: css, padding

HTML code:

```
<h1><a href="#">Hello World! Hello World!</a></h1>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;  /*For some known reasons*/
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}

h1 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 2%; /*Here is the problem, btw if i apply padding only to the sides (right and left) the phrase stay in one line ???*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

**[Preview](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYZOap)**

1. I don't want to delete the universal selector * rule
2. I don't want to change H1 display to inline
3. I don't want to use whitespace: nowrap;

So how can I keep the phrase in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that but i'm really pissed off i wasted so many hours and finally the problem was in using percentages '%', all i need to do is use em or rem or px, pfff why is that ?